# org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The program's entry point class could not be loaded due to a linkage failure

Tags: java, apache-flink

I am trying to submit a basic flink job to my Apache Flink Web Dashboard (localhost:8081) . This is my pom-

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafkaconsumer</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <target.java.version>1.8</target.java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-clients</artifactId>
      <version>1.15.1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
              <artifactSet>
                <excludes>
                  <exclude>org.apache.flink:flink-shaded-force-shading</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.slf4j:*</exclude>
                  <exclude>org.apache.logging.log4j:*</exclude>
                </excludes>
              </artifactSet>
              <filters>
                <filter>
                  <!-- Do not copy the signatures in the META-INF folder. Otherwise,
                    this might cause SecurityExceptions when using the JAR. -->
                  <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                  <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                  </excludes>
                </filter>
              </filters>
              <transformers>
                <transformer
                  implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                <transformer
                  implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                  <mainClass> com.flink.KafkaConsumer </mainClass>
                </transformer>
              </transformers>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build> 

    </project>
```

My jar file is getting successfully build. These are the contents of my jar -

```
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
META-INF/
com/
com/flink/
com/flink/KafkaConsumer.class
com/flink/Main.class
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/com.flink/
META-INF/maven/com.flink/kafkaconsumer/
META-INF/maven/com.flink/kafkaconsumer/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/com.flink/kafkaconsumer/pom.properties
```

On submitting my job jar file to Apache Flink Dashboard, i am getting server error with this-`org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The program's entry point class 'com.flink.KafkaConsumer' could not be loaded due to a linkage failure.`
Where am I going wrong? Please keep in mind that I am just starting with Flink and am learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of creating a maven springboot project,I created a maven project with no archetypes.it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a lack of dependencies in your **pom.xml**. I can see only `flink-clients` but you need at least `flink-streaming-java` [read here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/dev/configuration/overview/#flink-apis) and if you want to use Kafka you'll need a dependency for kafka connector.

- If you want to use a data format (avro, orc, parquet...) you need a dependency. [more here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/connectors/datastream/formats/overview/#datastream-formats)
- If you use a connector (jdbc, kafka, nifi...) [look here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/connectors/datastream/overview/#datastream-connectors)

Comment: I have added the dependencies,but I dont think they are necessary since I am not implementing any of their apis as of now. I added flink-core and flink-streaming-java. However I am still getting the same error-"linkage failure"

Comment: Some dependencies are mandatory like **flink-streaming-java** for executing core part of Flink. You probably should check the scope of your dependencies (**provided**, **test** ...) provided dependencies should be in flink/lib folder before starting your Flink server. Try to run an example jar (flink/examples) [like here](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/try-flink/local_installation/#submitting-a-flink-job)